# data model which is generated by edmx master is wrong. Some fields from views in SQL-server database is absent. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have unusuall problem with Entity Framework 6.1.3. There is a database on SQL-server. It contains tables and views. I need both of them for working. When I create a database model with EDMX-master's help I noticed that there is missing field from view (may be I will see later more). It is first. The second problem appears when I tried to get data from the same view. One field contain null. But in database it has string value. 
I don't know which materials can help you answer me. Do request. I will publicate what nessesary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making this a community wiki because it more sidesteps you question than answers it. However, it's important information for you and anyone else who stumbles across this to know.

I'm not sure why properties would be missing from your EDMX or why the values retrieved would be different from what's in your database, but EDMX is finicky by nature and prone to error, as a result. This is one of the primary reasons why the EF team has deprecated it. Yep, that's right, EDMX is deprecated and will be removed completely in EF 7, along with the associated model designer. Going forward, Code First will be the only way to work with Entity Framework. Despite the seemingly contradictory name, Code First can work with existing databases, as well. For more information on how to set that up, [see the post I wrote on the topic over on my blog](http://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/). For more information about the removal of EDMX from EF 7 and forward, [see the post by Rowan Miller of the EF team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx) that announced the change.

Anyways, while it doesn't answer your specific question, by using regular POCO Code First entities, you'll have complete control over the entities and you'll be able to know immediately why something does or does not work.